# cannot update my string and double arguemnts from two editText field in alertDialog - android studio

Tags: java, android, string, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog

My program is to calculating avarages of people and the program work dynamically (The number of names changes according to the user) so i want to let the user add people as he want by creating an `AlertDialog` Box, the problem is:
I tried to take the name and age from the `AlertDialog` but unfortunately my private variable are not updating...thank for helpers.

```
    private String name;  // Initialized later in the program to ""
    private Double age;   // also initilized to 0 
    .
    .
    . 
    .
    dmAvarage = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dmAvarage.setTitle("add");
    dmAvarage.setMessage("please enter name and age" + "\n");

    TextView lblName = new TextView(this);
    TextView lblPoints = new TextView(this);
    lblName.setText("name:");
    lblPoints.setText("age:");

    final EditText txtName = new EditText(this);
    final EditText txtPoints = new EditText(this);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.addView(lblName);
    layout.addView(txtName);
    layout.addView(lblPoints);
    layout.addView(txtPoints);

    dmAvarage.setView(layout);

     dmAvarage.setPositiveButton("add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            name = txtName.getText().toString();
            String str = txtPoints.getText().toString();
            if (!number(str)) {  //function to check if string is number
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            age = Double.parseDouble(str);

        }
    });
```

Comment: If answered post below don't work for you. Please provide more complete code for them to examine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below onClick() implementation: In the code onClick() implementation is basically in the Anonymous inner class, so I think thats why the value which you have updated there is not reflected back in outerclass, because that updation was in the scope of that other class(inner class). Please try once below code, here I extracted the code written in onClick() to a new method which is in scope of current Outer class. Please try once, It might work. Please tell me if any failure, I will debug it more to find out the exact root cause or solution.

```
     dmAvarage.setPositiveButton("add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            initializeNameAndAge();

        }
    });



  // This method is in Main(Outer) class.   
   private void initializeNameAndAge(){
            name = txtName.getText().toString();
            String str = txtPoints.getText().toString();
            if (!number(str)) {  //function to check if string is number
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            age = Double.parseDouble(str);
       }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip... i checked your solution but its give me a compilaton error couse the function dont recognize my EditText variables so i kind of improved the function and i let it get my two EditText variables but unfortunately it didnt change nothing.

Answer (score 0):

See,

You have taken both variables inside function, and therefore scope of both variables is only that function, now you are accessing dialog box from same function, but dialog box has its own scope and there for it will not access your variable, so better is

**Declare both variable at top as global so you can access it and used in dialog.**

Comment: yes .. i thought this the problem but in the beginnig i didnt wont to make a global variables and i was tried to create a function and through it i will access my variables.. and like you see it didnt work, so i tried your solution and i declare it as a global but unfortunately it didnt change nothing :(

Comment: did you get any log for this >

Comment: i dont think so... ... how can i check it?

Comment: just run your application and when you enter name or age and click ok at that time check in logcat, you will see so much log there you can find if any issue

Comment: I got only this:  getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa971c30